# getView() int keeps doubling every load

Tags: java, android, getview

I have this strange occurrence in my app. I am using the code I have list below to populate a TextView with the value of a counter. Every time the view gets refreshed the value of the counter double, I have set the counter to 0 after each cycle through but does not seem to work.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null) {
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layouttitle, container, false);
    }
    for (myStruct singleItem : myData) {
        counter++;
    }
    TextView totalsText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTotalsText);
    totalsText.setText("" + counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: getView method will get call evey time when it creates new view on the device. do not add counter in getview method it will never give you desired output

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to achieve by using counter variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getView()` method of Adapter called multiple times and there is no guarantee how many times it get called, so better don't use this method for any calculations or fro any other task which is relevant to number of items in your ListView.

And why `counter` is a global variable, can you explain it.

Comment: Yeah, general principle - a method whose name starts with `get` shouldn't change the visible internal state of the object you call it on.

Comment: Yeah agree with @DavidWallace, even if you are trying to update/change object of Adapter inside getView() that can cause issues.

Comment: So on display within a get and change only at the adapter level. I am wanting to add a total section in my view, what would be the best method, I am thinking to store in a db or array.

Comment: We cannot say like multiple times. When are all the user  requested for the layout, the getview () method will be called. Example: mobile is smaller device. So, each item views will be destroyed when it is hide from user visibility. Then it will be recreated again when the user scroll again back to old position.

Comment: @Ahamed Let us suppose your screen can display 4items at one time, then still there is no guarantee your getView() will be called only 4times. And item views never destroyed if you use holder pattern they just reused.

Comment: I understand that it will be recreated when the user scrolls etc.. I just don't get why the number doubles each time and not simply reused again (so staying the same number).